# Passing value from combobox to form 1

Tags: c#

I cannot get my head around this probably simple task, i have 2 forms, my main and a "footprints" one, in the footprints, i have a combobox with various .txt files loaded in, once i select a combobox value i'm trying to send the value to a label on form 1 the main one.

code for form 2:

```
    private void btnUpdateFootprints_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(@"LogicFiles\footprints.txt"))
        {
            // add footprints and add to .txt box
            File.WriteAllText(@"LogicFiles\" + comboBoxUseFootprints.Text, txtBoxFootprints.Text);
            FormMain.lblFootprintsUsed.Text = comboBoxUseFootprints.Text;
            this.Hide();
        } 
    }
```

This part "lblFootprintsUsed.Text" is the name of the label on form 1, the above code is in a button, once clicked it should hide and update the label, i'm getting:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'FormMain.lblFootprintsUsed'

I tried a few things but to be honest i never fully got how to reference form 1 without making a new form instance.

thanks for any help guys

Graham

Comment: can you edit your question and show the form1 code as well in regards to where you are using and or defining `lblFoorPrintsUsed` if this is a windows application, change the access level of the label from private to public ..hard to know without seeing the same code that you are looking at..

Answer (score 0):

```
FormMain.lblFootprintsUsed
```

This code is trying to set the static label of FormMain. However (correct me if I'm wrong) you have no static method in that form.

I guess that FormMain is the one that creates the footpronts form. In order to actually update the label of the main form you should raise an event from the footpronts form with the new value and subscribe to it from the main form.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/55555/Pass-value-between-forms-using-events